# Add 'updates' panel to SharePoint

Tags: update

I have a SharePoint system running on a private network,
since I need to notify my employees whether there are changes on our work or times, I need to have an update panel on our SharePoint site.
Which means I can add item to the panel, edit or delete if needed.

I really hope it can be done with web parts and not involve asp.net since I'm not really good at it, But I am familiar with JavaScript,Html and SharePoint system.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of information do you want to be able to update? Could this information be stored in a SharePoint list?

Comment: Yes, it's only one line. for example- "today we work for 8 hours instead of 6.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to be able to update, delete, etc. items, I would put the items you need to display in a SharePoint list and then use a List View Web Part to display the items on the page. Then you can easily interact with the List View Web Part to update, delete, and create new items without having to edit the page.

You could also create your list using the Announcements list template. Then you can use a List View Web Part to display the Announcements list on the page. You can also edit the List View Web Part properties and choose `Summary View` under the `Selected View` option -- this is will display the information in an announcement format like this:

[image: Example announcement web part]

**EDIT:**

Steps for how to do this (this is using SharePoint 2010, but I believe it's similar in SharePoint 2013).

1. Create a new list in SharePoint using the `Announcements` list template. Go to `Site Actions > More Options > Filter By: List > Announcements`. Give the list a name and click `Create`.
2. Create new items in the list with whatever information you want.
3. Go to the page where you want your Announcements to be and put the page in Edit mode. `Site Actions > Edit Page`.
4. Add the List View Web Part to display your Announcements list. On the Ribbon clikc `Insert > Web Part`. In the `Categories` pane, choose `Lists and Libraries`. In the `Web Parts` pane choose your Announcements list. Click `Add`.
5. Edit the List View Web Part properties. Click the drop-down arrow on the List View Web Part and click `Edit Web Part` to open the web part properties.

[image: edit the web part]

6. Change the List View Web Part view to `Summary View`. In the List View Web Part properties box under `Selected View` click the drop-down menu and select `Summary View`. A pop-up box may appear confirming the change, just click `Ok`. At the bottom of the web part properties box click `Apply` then `Ok`.
7. Save your page. In the Ribbon click the `Page` tab and then `Save & Close`. If you're using a Publishing a page you'll also need to Check-in the page and Publish it for others to see your changes.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.
So if i understood you correctly- 
1. I have to open a new list view page
2. I need to add a list view web part on the main page that will display the list view page items?

Comment: @Yakirbu I added some how-to steps in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I use SharePoint 2013, I"ll try to implement it tomorrow and I hope it's same as 2010.